# What are Technetium's physical stress characteristics?

Tags: transition-metals, periodic-table, metallurgy

I've looked at periodic and data tables from several sources, but none give mechanical / engineering property data on Technetium.  Why is this?

Comment: [Tc is unstable](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/12390/41328) ans is certainly not a constructing material, but it doesn't mean there is no data for it. What mechanical properties are you interested in, exactly?

Comment: Elastic moduli of polycrystal Technetium: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022508870900391